# C++ Priority Queue implementation to sort graph edges

Tags: c++, graph, stl, priority-queue

I am trying to sort graph edges but am unable to do so. 
Given below is my implementation of a priority queue to achieve the same.

```
  class CompareDistance
    {
        public:    
            bool operator()(pair<int,int> n1,pair<int,int> n2)
            {
                if(g[n1.first][n2.second] < g[n2.first][n2.second])
                return true;
                else
                return false;
           }
    };
    int g[3][3] = {{4,1,3},{3,3,3},{3,3,3}};//graph edges


int main()
{

    priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int> >,CompareDistance> pq;


    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
            pq.push(pair<int,int>(i,j));

    cout<<"\t"<<g[pq.top().first][pq.top().second];//does not give the correct result
    pq.pop();




    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please state what is your goal, and formulate a question...

Comment: I have edited it for better understanding, i want the the priority queue to contain pair of node values in sorted order of distances in the graph- @WojciechFrohmberg

Comment: @HARJATINSINGH Is there a good reason you're trying to put them all into a PQ instead of simply making an vector and sorting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not compile, but that is an easy fix. I assume g contains the edge weights. There is a bug in here:

```
if(g[n1.first][n2.second] < g[n2.first][n2.second])
```

It should be

```
if(g[n1.first][n1.second] < g[n2.first][n2.second])
```

Mind the name of the second index on the left.
**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c75c26d7d3897e43)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

OK so if I understood you correctly you have a directed graph (like in example complete graph of three nodes). With each of the arc there is associated value -- weight and what you need is to sort the collection of arcs by this value. 
First of all you should probably create the collection of arcs. I don't think the priority_queue is the best of your option. I would use the vector here because of the simplicity:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>> arcs;
```

Where the first pair would contain the arc weight and the directed pair of the nodes between which the arc exists.
Next after you add all of the nodes you simply sort the collection specifing the custom function to compare. If you use c++11 it could look as follows:

```
std::sort(arcs.begin(), arcs.end(), 
          [] (const std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>& a,
              const std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>& b) { 
                  return a.first < b.first; 
              });
```

Comment: If you want to have sorted collection of arcs online modifiable you could should consider using std::multiset.

Comment: This is the kind of solution I'd go for but maybe preferring std::tuple with 3 fields for an arc if not a struct even because nested std::pairs are quite impractical and can become difficult to understand when you have to code things such as `a.second.first` or `a.second.second`. It becomes increasingly easier to make logical mistakes.